# direct mp3 file-transfer from a Kiosk to a smartphone

Tags: android, ios, file-transfer, kiosk

I'm building a Kiosk, using a MacMini and an Elotouch display. It would load a CoreAnimation based App. that plays multimedia content following user touch-based choices.

I'm in a early stage of the project. I can change the architecture/technology if needed.

I need that my Kiosk could also distribute mp3 content to Smartphones close to it, wirelessly.
For now I would like to support iOS and Android phones. I don't have any control on the smartphone side. The Kiosk is coin-operated (with time based session expiration) and connected to the web through a wifi network, managed by me.

**Can you tell me a common, safe and simple way to accomplish this?**

I thought to WebDav but I would like to explore alternatives, the simpler for the user-side the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one-time/session-based URLs, displaying a QR code on your kiosk screen would be one way to get the download URL to the device (and invalidated after successful download/session expiration); this would require a QR code reader which neither iOS nor Android have built in, though, but many users have one.

Additionally, display the same URL that's encoded in the QR code using URL shortener service like bit.ly, goo.gl, etc. for the user to type in.

This way there's no set up for the user, no funny business with pushing data to the user (privacy/security concerns) and every smartphone does have a web browser.

Comment: I like the idea of using both qr-codes and shortened urls. Since the content is mainly .mp3 files do you think the browser will be enough? Those file are a sort of "souvenir" for the user, that can consume them right there or later.

Comment: The browser shouldn't be a problem. If you link directly to the MP3 file, Android will auto-play (just tested this) and I *assume* iOS does the same (no iOS device around right now). So you might want to link to an HTML page and provide two links: One directly to the MP3 and one to the MP3 as download, e.g. some `x-application/download` MIME type -- Android should handle this fine, not sure about iOS. I'm sure there is docs about this out on the web, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is by using OBEX Push and bluetooth. 
There are plenty of command-line tools to list all bluetooth devices nearby, and to do a file transfer to one of them.

The user would just need to activate bluetooth discovery on his cell phone, search for the phone on the kiosk, and select his phone.

Another alternative is mail. WebDAV is a bad idea, because the user will have to type in the address (cumbersome!).

A lot of photo kiosks are already using OBEX Push to receive photos from phones.

The easiest is to provide different types of usb cables: micro-usb, mini-usb... Almost all cell phones can be attached as a USB disk nowadays.

Summary:
* OBEX Push
* USB connect
* Mail

Comment: I would never plug in any cable from a public kiosk into a device that stores all of my mail, contacts and calendars and knows most of my passwords, even less so if that kiosk is supposed to *write* data. Mailing would require the user to give up his mail address (personal information) and might be a problem depending on the size of the file (inbox limits).

Comment: I'm a little bit concerned about your push solution because of security reasons. USB connection is not an option, It has to be wireless.

Comment: @microspino: What security reasons are there that limit OBEX push? The bluetooth stack is encrypted by default, and the user needs to accept the file on his phone before any file transfer even occurs. If you do not want your users to give up personal information, this is as far as I know the only way to do it. The other options all include needing to give a destination address (mail, phone number for MMS transfer, ...)